# Automate uploading docs to livelink (open text) without human intervention

Tags: linux

Is it possible to have a script/application to automate uploading docs from a linux box to livelink data server without someone's intervention?  If so, can you show me a direction on how to start the process?

Thank you,
Bob

Comment: Do you mean OpenText Livelink?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inotify to monitor a directory for changes and then upload the documents to a live link WebDAV gateway.

Answer (score 0):

OpenText's [File System Archiving](http://www.opentext.com/2/global/products/products-archiving/products-opentext-file-system-archiving.htm) will do this.